# Why do I get 'undefined' error when I try to read session atrribute from Controller

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

In controller, I have set session attribute

`HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("Anshu", true);`

In JSP,I am trying to get value from session

`<input type=hidden id=file value="${sessionScope.Anshu}" />`

In JavaScript,trying to display that value..

`var nish=document.getElementById("file").value;
alert(nish.value);`

But, when I am trying to run the code ,I am getting 'Undefined' in alert statement.
Can anyone tell me whay its coming 'undefined' ?
Thanks in advance ! :-)

Comment: This isn’t an error. `scrambled` is already the `value`, which is a string. A string doesn’t have a `value` property.

Comment: I changed scrambled name...Still,I am getting same error

Comment: Why exactly have you changed the variable name? The variable name was perfectly fine. Did you not understand my comment?

Comment: Could U elaborate a bit,Please ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and append the modified code — the one where you added quotes and a space in your HTML and the JavaScript where you’ve removed one of the two `.value`s?

Comment: @Xufox Followings are my modified code-  In JSP <input type="file" id="file " value="${sessionScope.Anshu}" /> and in JavaScript var nish=document.getElementById("file");
        alert(nish.value);

Comment: Really `id="file "`? Remove the space!

Comment: @Xufox I removed, Still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this: `<input type=hidden id=filevalue="${sessionScope.Anshu}" />`

it should be like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="file" value="${sessionScope.Anshu}" />
```

plus in your javascript code you don't have to say `.value` twice. once is enough.

Comment: I tried whatever u said..Still, I am getting same error.

Comment: I don't know anything about jsp, but if the `${sessionScope.Anshu}` works (use Ctrl + U to confirm) and you solve the javascript part, then you should be good to go.

Comment: When I use Ctlr + U, I find that the value of `${sessionScope.Anshu}` is blank..Can u help me out ..

Comment: then it has JSP problem too. I can't help. sorry.

Comment: Then, because of JSP the output is coming as "Undefined" ??

Comment: no, it should output empty. it outputs undefined because you didn't fix the javascript error i guess. use this `var nish=document.getElementById("file");`

Comment: Now,output is empty. Thanks for the help u extended :-)